# wostringstream to LPWSTR for MessageBoxW function

Tags: c++

I seem to be missing something in regards to converting a wostringstream to a LPCWSTR.

```
void counter_error(const wstring& input) {
    wostringstream tempss;
    tempss << L"Cannot find counter " << input;
    LPCWSTR temp = tempss.str().c_str();
    MessageBoxW(0, temp, L"ERROR", 0);
}
```

The "ERROR" caption shows up fine but the text below is garbled. I thought that it might be the c_str() function returning a regular char array instead of a wchar array but intellisense is telling me it returns a wchar array.

Comment: There's no need for a string stream here. `temp` is a dangling pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks problematic:

```
LPCWSTR temp = tempss.str().c_str();
```

`tempss.str()` creates a temporary string which is destroyed at the end.

Try

```
void counter_error(const wstring& input) {
    wostringstream tempss;
    tempss << L"Cannot find counter " << input;
    wstring temp_str = tempss.str();
    LPCWSTR temp = temp_str.c_str();
    MessageBoxW(0, temp, L"ERROR", 0);
}
```

Or, as **@JoachimPileborg** suggested, consider

```
MessageBoxW(0, (wstring(L"Cannot find counter " + input).c_str(), ...)
```

It still creates a temporary variable, but it is not going to be destroyed before returning from `MessageBoxW`.

Comment: Or just `MessageBoxW(0, (wstring(L"Cannot find counter ") + input).c_str(), ...)`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yep, sure. I updated the answer. (I was not focusing on the shortest solution, rather on what's incorrect in the given one.)

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the object lifetimes here, LPCWSTR const & temp = tempss.str().c_str(); will not work because although it extends the lifetime of the wchar_t * temporary it does not extend the lifetime of the string returned by tempss.str() (the underlying array to which wchar_t * from c_str() points to)